# How do wireless access points work?

Tags: network, wireless, access-point, capwap

**I understand what the intent of wireless access points are** but I am struggling to understand them fully on a deeper level. So, do wireless access points have their own network with their own IP addresses/SSID's that you need to connect to in order for it to communicate with the main network, or do they just simply show up as a discoverable network device that connects to the main router/main internet?

**For example**, **if my default gateway of my main home network were 10.0.0.1, could the wireless access point show up as something like 10.0.0.30?** and it would use the 10.0.0.1 to go to the internet?, or is it hopping over another unique network with different IPs?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wireless access point is Layer 2 functionality. Whatever ip processing (Layer 3) it is also capable of doing is not specific for the Wireless access part and depends on the exact device. So, generally speaking, every option is possible. Depending on your setup some may not result in working network.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: it depends on what your particular gateway and your particular access point do and how they are connected. Also, this is a question about home networking, and it is better suited for https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com/ (not sure which one)

Comment: My mistake I guess I was trying to find out how wireless bridging works. I forgot to add that in the main question

Comment: if it is a bridge, it technically does not have to have IP at all, it can just forward layer 2 frames based on mac addresses to your gateway, or whatever is between gateway and access point.

Comment: I just don't get this. Some people say they have an IP that's the on the same network as the default gateway, others say that it doesn't have an IP at all and others say that they have their own separate network with separate unique IP's. Like what's the deal here?

Comment: well, wireless access point is pretty useless if it can only do wireless access, so it needs to have some way to connecting to the outside. Now, this way can be either layer 2 or layer 3 (provided that the device can actually do layer 2 or layer 3, and it usually can do at least one). so, it is possible to have all the setups that you described, and you can choose from. There is no unique option, there are several.

Comment: you can have an AP as either as a bridge or a router. if AP is a bridge, it just takes packets from the the WLAN and forwards them to whatever it is connected to, without changing anything. You either need to ensure that there are no loops in the topology, or have (R)STP speking between your devices. In this case your host will need the IP of the router as default gateway, and then it forwards frames to its IP and its MAC. In this case AP itself does not need an IP, unless you want to connect to the AP itself (e.g., to configure it). Since the devices are in the same layer 2 segment,

Comment: AP needs an IP from the same range. If your AP can be a router, you can set up a separate subnet with separate IP/Mask for your WLAN. Then your hosts will have IP of the AP as default gateway, and AP needs to know how to route packets to the router/device with internet connection (unless of course AP is this device itself). You can either statically configure AP with routes or let AP and that router run a routing protocol (probably overkill). In this case AP can actually have more than one IP address, one for WLAN, and one for each other interface that is up.

Comment: there is no good explanation why both layer 2 and layer 3 can forward packet. setting up layer 2 forwarding (bridging) with ethernet is simply easier than setting up working layer 3 with IP, so this is what we have now :) I don't recommend trying to understand why it is this way.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a WAP is a network bridge. It forwards between wired Ethernet and wireless 802.11 based on each frame's destination MAC address. It uses an IP address for management only.

Some "WAPs" may actually be routers, creating a distinctive IP subnet behind them. Strictly speaking, that isn't a WAP any more. Note that home networks are explicitly off-topic here.

In on-topic networks, you usually separate your wireless network from the wired one by IP subnet, but you do so using a VLAN with appropriate SSID association and you don't route between those on the WAP but on a separate firewall/router. The WAP bridges between a wireless SSID-based network and a wired VLAN that connects to the router.